# Selecting the Same Value with OnItemSelectListener

Tags: android, spinner

This has been asked many times here but I have no idea why this is not working for me. I have multiple spinners on my layout and they are updated depending on the selected previous spinner(s) values. I want to be able to select a value more than once on the same spinner.

I am having a problem using this code:

```
public class NDSpinner extends Spinner {

  public NDSpinner(Context context)
  { super(context); }

  public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  { super(context, attrs); }

  public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

  @Override public void
  setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
  {
    boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
    super.setSelection(position, animate);
    if (sameSelected) {
      // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
      getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
    }
  }

  @Override public void
  setSelection(int position)
  {
    boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
    super.setSelection(position);
    if (sameSelected) {
      // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
      getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
    }
  }
}
```

This should be working with my existing code, but for some reason it is not.

I have multiple spinners and here is just one of them showing that I am using it:

```
vTypeSpinner = (NDSpinner) findViewById(R.id.typeSpinner);
```

Here is my XML showing that I am referencing it:

```
<com.example.productguide.NDSpinner
    android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView01"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView01" />
```

Here is the LogCat error

```
12-27 10:05:06.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.productguide/com.example.productguide.PowersportsEquivalent}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class com.example.productguide.NDSpinner
```

Here is more of the LogCat that I didn't see before for some reason:

```
12-27 10:05:06.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.productguide.NDSpinner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.productguide-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.productguide-2, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: What is `DropDownSpinner` in your xml?

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed those, the LogCat is updated. now to `12-27 10:05:06.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.productguide/com.example.productguide.PowersportsEquivalent}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class com.example.productguide.NDSpinner`

Comment: that logcat error doesn't look related to your code but to a problem in your xml file...

Comment: Here is more of the LogCat that I didn't see before for some reason: `12-27 10:05:06.165: E/AndroidRuntime(3089): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.productguide.NDSpinner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.productguide-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.productguide-2, /system/lib]]`

Answer (score 0):

have one dummy value in the spinner which is always first. And have one validation check for spinner like value selected proper or not. if value selected is a dummy value then check should fail.

Comment: I don't need a spinner that has multiple selections. I need a spinner where I can select the already selected value again, if needed. The way that OnItemSelectedListener works is only when the selected value is changed. I need it so I can select any value even if it is already selected. [This might give more understanding of what I need.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975394/how-to-use-android-spinner-like-a-drop-down-list)

Comment: I don't want to use any dummy values in my spinners/database.